# Node.js exports return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I have the following module:

```
exports.CONSTANT = "aaaa";

function a() { ... }

module.exports = { a };
```

For some reasons, when I import like this:

```
const { CONSTANT, a } = require("./myModule");
```

the method "a" is defined, but **the constant "CONSTANT" is undefined**.

Why is this happening?

Comment: With the line `module.exports = { a };` aren't you just overriding the `exports` line?

Comment: @Andy I think that this is the error too. But didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`module.exports` overrides the first `export` and gets returned from the `require()` call at the end. If you put some logs:

```
exports.CONSTANT = "aaaa";

function a() {}

console.log(module.exports); // {CONSTANT: "aaaa"}

module.exports = { a };

console.log(module.exports); // {a: ƒ a()}
```

Try this:

```
const CONSTANT = "aaaa";

function a() {}

module.exports = { CONSTANT, a };
```

Or this:

```
export const CONSTANT = "aaaa";

export function a() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning the value of module.exports. To fix this, you can do the following:

```js
function a() { ... }

module.exports = {
    CONSTANT: "aaaaa",
    a: a
}

// OR

module.exports.CONSTANT = "aaaaa";

function a() { ... }

module.exports.a = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to fit multiple variables in this way `{ CONSTANT, a}`, so I recommend that you fit multiple variables in this way:

```
{ 
     var1,
     var2,
}
```

For example:

```
const { 
     CONSTANT, 
     a
} = require("./Module");
```